# Javascript function to remove specific element from array based on two conditions / two properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

How to remove element from array based on two values?
E.g. element with `day: 8, date: august 2021.'`

Array:

```
var events = 
  [ { day:  8, date: 'july 2021.'   } 
  , { day: 16, date: 'july 2021.'   } 
  , { day:  8, date: 'august 2021.' } 
  , { day: 16, date: 'august 2021.' } 
  ]
```

e.g. if I click on `day 8, august` I want to remove just element
`8, august` not also `8, july`

What I tried:

```
// number of the day clicked $scope.newEvent (8)
// date of day clicked $scope.selectedDate ("august 2021.")

var newEventsArray = events.filter(e => 
  e.day != $scope.newEvent && e.date == $scope.selectedDate)
```

Comment: what's the actual value of `$scope.newEvent` and `$scope.selectedDate`?

Comment: // number of the day clicked $scope.newEvent = 8
// date of day clicked $scope.selectedDate = "august 2021."

Comment: You need `... != ... || ... != ...` (the filter function needs to return true if either one doesn't match)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there already, it's a bit of a logic error. Say we write the day being equal as `D`, and the month/year being equal as `M`.

You now filter out all of them such that

```
!D & M
```

Meaning if `D=8` and `M=August`, you would filter out all dates for which the day is *is not* equal to `8`, and for which the month *is* equal to `August`.

What you want, is to remove the entry only when the day *and* the month are equal to the values, that is

```
D & M
```

Now of course, using this as a filter would yield *only* 8, August, so you want to invert it

```
!(D & M)
!D | !M
```

In other words, you should change your expression to the following:

```js
var newEventsArray = events.filter(e => e.day !== $scope.newEvent || e.date !== $scope.selectedDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

Im, expecting you are printing the button using

```
events.map((item, id) => <Item />)
```

if thats the case you have access to item **id**, and you can delete the exact item using **id**